# Unity: Colors are Brighter on Android Device

Tags: android, colors, unity-game-engine

I have an Android App I´m developing in unity. Colors look just fine on the game editor, but when I build the app and use it on My Samsung Galaxy S4, all the colors seem to be brighter than on the Unity Editor. I have all my images on True Color. Even the background colors and button colors of the UI get brighter.

Can anyone tell me how to get the same colors I get on my Unity editor when I build the app on my device?

Thank you

Comment: Most probably the device is just set brighter Unless you mean washed out? Try to take a screenshot of the game running on the device and look it on the pc. If it looks like the pc, then the device is set too bright. If it looks washed out, then something's off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your game pictures from your laptop to your mobile device then you see even with same pictures they looks different and it's because difference to their quality and it's not unity or your fault.

Comment: It Seems like The problem Is in The sceeen. The sceeenshot looks fine on my pc. I'll see if I can change color saturation or brightness in my phone.